# Why is Grunt ignoring jQuery when Uglifying?

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-uglify

I can't figure out why jQuery is being ignored when running my Grunt task. Here is what it looks like:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        // Concat
        concat: {
            js: {
                src: [
                    'js/vendor/jquery.js',
                    'js/app/graph.js',
                ],
                dest: 'app/build/js/app.js'
            }
        },
        // Uglify
        uglify: {
            options: {
                preserveComments: false
            },
            my_target: {
                files: {
                    'app/build/js/app.min.js': [
                            'app/build/js/app.js'
                        ]
                }
            }
        });
};
```

When I check `app.js`, jQuery is part of it, but not in `app.min.js`. So I suspect something is wrong with the Uglify part.

Comment: Have you tried cleaning before building? Also, do you have a task that runs these sequentially, making sure concat is run before uglify?

Comment: Yes concat does run before uglify. `grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify']);`. How do I clean?

Comment: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean

This is not strictly necessary, jQuery should be included if that's all you've got. Do a test on the included site to be sure it's not just hiding somewhere in the uglified code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-clean This is not strictly necessary, jQuery should be included if that's all you've got. Do a test on the included site to be sure it's not just hiding somewhere in the uglified code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your syntax is right, please try instead this:

```
    uglify: {
        development: {
            options: {
                preserveComments: false
            },
            files: {
                'app/build/js/app.min.js': 'app/build/js/app.js'
            }
    }
```

And call it as: `grunt.registerTask('default', ['concat', 'uglify:development']);`

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me. Btw I think you are missing `}` in the 2nd last line.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help at all or if there even is any difference between the two, but you could try setting up your uglify config similarly to your concat config... e.g:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    // Configuration
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        // Concat
        concat: {
            js: {
                src: [
                    'js/vendor/jquery.js',
                    'js/app/graph.js',
                ],
                dest: 'app/build/js/app.js'
            }
        },
        // Uglify
        uglify: {
            options: {
                preserveComments: false
            },
            js: {
                src: ['app/build/js/app.js'],
                dest: ['app/build/js/app.min.js']
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Also, I think you were missing an extra bracket

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work me, but I do like this style more.